# Data Connection Files

Tags: infopath, data, connection

I have been asked to provide an explanation why we have files in two places for Administrator Approved templates.

We have not been deleting the data connection files in the SharePoint Data Connection library after uploading the .ucdx files to Central Administration.  We leave them for a purpose which is to reuse them when we later update an existing InfoPath form template and want to preview and check before publishing.  Another benefit is that the data connections can also be used for other templates.

Should I be deleting the data connection files in the data connection library instead?

Answer (score 0):

That's a legitimate reason--for testing. If you do not have a testing/staging environment, this would be the best place for testing, however, you can use the central administration data connection library for testing as well, just name the data connection something like "DataConnectionTest.udcx", and then when you are ready, just replace the data connection file with the test with the correct name.

Comment: Thank you for your good answer.  We move our templates from our test environment to staging and production using source files.  After changing the source files to another environment, we prefer to preview the template to make sure all's well.  Since we cannot access the Central Admin data connections in 'Preview', there is no way we can do that and would have to test the published form in the browser.  Is that still a valid reason to keep the data connection files in both places?

Comment: We are not able to access the central administration data connection library in InfoPath preview since it is not a published template.  Does it make a difference that we have SharePoint 2007?